# norm of matrix powers if spectral radius is at most 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a matrix whose spectral radius $\rho(A) < 1$. Can anything be said about $\|A^2\|_2, \|A^3\|_2, \dots$ in relation to $\|A\|_2$?

I know that $\|A^k\| \le \|A\|^k$ but I am looking for something else. Can it be said that $\|A^k\|_2 \le \|A\|_2$?

The other result I could find is [from these notes](https://orion.math.iastate.edu/keinert/math507/notes/chapter5.pdf) which say that $A^k \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Gelfand's theorem states that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \|A^k\|^{1/k} = \rho(A)$; you can get a lot out of that.

Comment: For instance: for any $\rho(A)<r<1$, there exists a $K$ such that for all $k>K$ we have
$
\|A^k\| \leq r^k.
$

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but for any $\epsilon >0$ there is an induced norm such that $\rho(A) \le \|A\| \le \rho(A)+\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

The condition $\rho(A) < 1$ for $n \times n$ matrices does not restrict $\|A^k\|_2$ for any $k < n$.  For example, if $A$ has entries $t$ on the first super-diagonal and $0$ everywhere else (i.e. $t$ times a single Jordan block of size $n$ for eigenvalue $0$), we have $\|A^k \|_2 = |t|^k$ for $1 \le k \le n-1$ but $\rho(A) = 0$.

Comment: What if $\rho(A) \neq 0$?

Comment: The example can easily be modified..